# Is there any way to display two data in one row using Rowspan in HTML TABLE?

Tags: php, html, css

Im setting up a html table that connected from the database. But I want the table design like the excel which in html table using rowspan. but I cant work out the problem which Im working out.

Please help me to create this format. See the code below

```
<tbody>
  <?php
    include_once('connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rqn ";

      $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $result = $row['rqn_no'];
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><?php echo $row['rqn_no'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date_filed'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['desc_text'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['remarks'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date_approved'] ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php
          include_once('connection.php');
          $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  po_data where po_data.rqn_base = $result ";
          $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
            ?>

              <?php echo $row1['po_no'] ?>

            <?php
          }
        ?> 
        </td>
      </tr>

    <?php 
   }
  ?>      
</tbody>
```

Result I Wanted:
https://prnt.sc/md2t2s

Actual Result:https://prnt.sc/md2tpk

Comment: can po_no be more than 2 values or it will be max 2?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi , there will be no limit as long as there are data that matches the RQN data.

Comment: You could add 1 more query to count and add them to variable as `rowspan` value.

Comment: @Mukyuu already did that but using rowspan was the problem because it will rearrange the second row.

Comment: Actually if you're not fixated on using `rowspan` probably you could use `hr` see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tf5qgzyd/)

Comment: @Mukyuu hi I already fixed the answer, Thank you for the idea. But i Find a way to still use the rowspan :D.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowspan` with a `div` to achieve the result you want. Try this,

```
<tbody>
  <?php
    include_once('connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rqn ";

      $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $result = $row['rqn_no'];
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><?php echo $row['rqn_no'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date_filed'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['desc_text'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['remarks'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date_approved'] ?></td>

        <?php
          include_once('connection.php');
          $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  po_data where po_data.rqn_base = $result ";
          $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
          // open <td>
          echo "<td rowspan=$total_rows>";

          while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
            ?>

              <?php echo "<div style='border-bottom:1px solid black'>" . $row1['po_no'] ."</div>" ?>

            <?php
          }

          // close </td>
          echo "</td>";
        ?> 
        </td>
      </tr>

    <?php 
   }
  ?>      
</tbody>
```

Adjust the CSS according to your need.

Comment: I think this is just a mismatch of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the final answer to my result.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T73V3.png)

```
<tbody>
<?php 
    include ("connection.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rqn ";
    $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
      $ename = $row['rqn_no'];
      // count the esal in each ename
      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM po_data WHERE rqn_base=$ename";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
      $count_result2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
?>
<tr >
    <td rowspan="<?php echo $count_result2; ?>"><?php echo $row['rqn_no']; ?></td>
    <td rowspan="<?php echo $count_result2; ?>"><?php echo $row['date_filed']; ?></td>
    <td rowspan="<?php echo $count_result2; ?>"><?php echo $row['desc_text']; ?></td>
    <td rowspan="<?php echo $count_result2; ?>"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></td>
    <td rowspan="<?php echo $count_result2; ?>"><?php echo $row['date_approved']; ?></td>
    <?php
          // loop each esal
      while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)):
          ?>
    <td><?php echo $row2['po_no']; ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php
          endwhile; // endwhile for each esal looping
    endwhile; // endwhile for the main looping
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Tnx for helping me guys